# Android Studio: Flexible Gridlayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, responsive-design

I started to create an app with the gridlayout. After I wrote the XML-knote of the gridlayout I placed within the gridlayout several buttons.

[image]

But if I change the Android Device from Nexus N to Nexus S the Layout starts to look like this:

[image]

and the same problem with the size goes on with Nexus XL

[image]

What should I do to keep the layout size of Nexus N to all the other devices?

Comment: add your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

height = displayMetrics.heightPixels /NumberOfButtons;

width=displayMetrics.widthPixels/3;

You need to set the button height dynamaically at the runtime 
Through above code you can get height and width of screen.

Comment: I try it at home. Thx. :)